# Pass setOf as Parameter to a function. How can that be accomplished?

Tags: kotlin

I have to write a function, which takes three sets as parameter.

The signatur looks this way:

```
fun twoInThree(a: setOf<Int>, b: setOf<Int>, c: setOf): setOf<Int> {}
```

But it doesn't seem possible. The compiler complains. With ArrayList it would possible theoretically.

What am I doing wrong? **How can the desired declaration be accomplished?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setOf()` is a function, not a type. You call it to create instances of `Set<T>`.

When defining arguments for your custom `twoInThree` function, what you want is the `Set<T>` type instead:

```kotlin
fun twoInThree(a: Set<Int>, b: Set<Int>, c: Set<Int>): Set<Int> {}
```

Some extra notes:

- Your confusion with `ArrayList` probably comes from the fact that the constructor `ArrayList()` (which is a function that returns an instance of `ArrayList`) really looks like the *type* `ArrayList<T>`.
- Using `ArrayList` as the type for variables and function arguments is usually discouraged (even though it is perfectly valid). Instead, we prefer staying more general and use the `List<T>` interface instead.

Comment: This also demonstrates why the Kotlin coding conventions strongly prefer classes to start with a capital letter, and methods/functions to start with a lower-case letter, making them easy to distinguish.

Comment: @gidds true, however this convention doesn't apply to constructors, which are 2 parens away from the corresponding class name, and still bring this sort of confusion :D